# mootools disable or intercept an added event

Tags: events, mootools, intercept

let's say i do this:

```
$('field').addEvents ({
  'focus' : function() { // do some stuff }
  'blur' : function() { // do other stuff }
});
```

this is the default behaviour for all my text input fields. what i now want to do is something like this

`<button id='shinyButton' name='shinyButton'>Poke Me</button>`

then:

```
$('shinyButton').addEvent('click', function() {
  stopDefaultBlurFunctionInCurrentlyFocussedField();
  // do seriously cool stuff
  if (finishedDoingSeriouslyCoolStuff) {
    $('field').focus();  // return focus to input field
  }
}
```

so:

1) how do i stopDefaultBlurFunctionInCurrentlyFocussedField();?

2) how do i tell if i'm actually finishedDoingSeriouslyCoolStuff?

Comment: clicking on a button whilst focused on field is tricky, it will fire off a blur as well as the click. you can either use a small delay on the blur callback that you can clear on the click - NOT ideal as the click can be a long click by virtue of the mouse held longer than expected - or you can go with delegation for all these to the parent form where you can check the eventTargets etc... it's not an easy task. you can probably also add mouseover event on the button that sets a flag on the fields that the blur checks and exits gracefully...

Comment: gotcha.  so for my intents and purposes: NO.  :D  thanks again @Dimitar.  as a sidenote, i see you are also self-taught.  gives me hope!  lol.

Comment: nah- it can work. check http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/edsqg/1/ - like i said, disables the blur event on the required field if you mouseover the submit so a click on it won't trigger field validation. any other blur will.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking you can't do what you want to do because the `blur` event fires before your click handler does.

Dimitar's suggestion of disabling the event on mouseover works fine for mouse users, but prevents users from triggering the button with the keyboard.

One option (but a bit of a hack) would be to introduce a tiny delay into the `blur` event handler, and use a variable flag to control the event firing (you might need to tune the delay so it's imperceptible but still long enough for your purposes:

```
var disableBlurMethod = false;

$('field').addEvents ({
  'focus' : function() { // do some stuff }
  'blur' : function() {
    (function() {
      if (!disableBlurMethod) {
        // do some stuff
      }
    }).delay(50);
  }
});

$('shinyButton').addEvent('click', function() {
  disableBlurMethod = true;
  // do seriously cool stuff
  if (finishedDoingSeriouslyCoolStuff) {
    disableBlurMethod = false;
    $('field').focus();  // return focus to input field
  }
}
```